# Check if there is phone number in string C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I read a string that includes all types of characters. I want to check whether there is in the string, consisting of sub-string at least 7 digits. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Phone numbers: `01-555-1234` `+11 (345) 555 4444` (see where this is going?) Can you post an example of your text?

Comment: Germany (e.g.) usually has another phone number schema than the U.S. numbers. This was an issue to me in the past when buying from U.S. stores that have "clever" phone number validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a regular expression

```
[0-9]{7,}

bool includesPhone = Regex.IsMatch("phone number 123456789", "[0-9]{7,}");
```

Comment: I don't want to check if whole string is phone number, I just want to check if the string contains phone number (and block it).

Comment: Thank you. One more thing.. if I want to block email address too, Can I add this to this regex? or I need a new one?

Comment: You need another regex cause email validation is quite complicated. Search for email and regex here on stackoverflow and oyu will find examples for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Regex` - something like `\d{7,}`

Answer (score 2):

Use this: `var match= Regex.Match(s,"\d{7}")`

Here s is your string. Now match contains the data matching the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Regular expresion for this task . The regex pattern depends on the format of the phone number ...