# Web scraping a telephone number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am new to the HtmlAgilityPack and its a bit unclear for me how it exactly works. Lets say when something like this piece of code is written

```
Dim url1 As String = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=Verizon
Dim hw As New HtmlWeb()
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = hw.Load(url1)
For Each link As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")

Dim att As HtmlAttribute = link.Attributes("href")
Response.Write(att.Value)

Next
```

1. So when the `SelectNodes` is `//a[@href]` does that mean that it will only look at `ahref` tags?
2. If so how can I make it consider other tags in within the loop like `<li>, <h3>, <div>`.
   Is it correct like `//li[@class='wrap']|//div[@class='last']` ??
3. How can the data between those tags be fetched and presented.

One other issue is that lets say I need to scrape a telephone number from that url, the number might be unavailable or might not be in any of the tags defined. Is there any reliable method that I can work on in order to obtain a telephone number to a relative search term? Any suggestions or thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the current xpath looks at anchor tags that have a href parameter. I suggest you read up on xpath syntax (for instance at http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

To select other nodes you need to change the xpath to select those tags, for instance:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li")
```

to get all li nodes etc.

The data in the tags can be reached using the InnerHtml of the selected document nodes (link.InnerHtml in your example)

Automatically scraping telephone numbers is a real pain, every country uses different lengths and there are many different formats to write down a number: +12(0)3456 +123456 00123456 +12(0)34-56 are all the same valid phone number... See [Check if there is phone number in string C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607103/check-if-there-is-phone-number-in-string-c-sharp) for a simple sollution

GL&HF!